# jQuery validator: Form refuses to validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, forms, jquery-validate

I have a simple Javascript file that needs to run. I know it is rendered fine, as the input masking portion works perfectly. However, the form will not validate when I input information. If I for example put in a phone number 4 digits log, then check for validation, it returns 'true'. It does not use unobtrusive validation. The project is a simple ASP.NEt MVC website written on a Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 platform. The page in question on the website is the EditInfo page, for your reference. There must be some variable I need to set to get this working, but I do not know what it is. Thanks for your help and have a great day.

First, here is the BundleConfig.cs file. This portion (not the whole file) is the jquery.validate plug-in.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                    "~/Scripts/additional-methods.js",
                    "~/Scripts/additional-methods.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.selectric.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"));
```

The bundle is rendered in the layout page.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

The app.js file contains functions used in error placement as well as the jquery.validator default settings.

```
if ($.validator) {
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {

        if (!validator.numberOfInvalids())
            return;

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(validator.errorList[0].element).offset().top - 150
        }, 'fast');

        $(validator.errorList[0].element).focus();

    },
    onkeyup: false
});
}
//
// Name:  errorPlacementValidator
// Description:  Used by the validator.
//
function errorPlacementValidator(error, element) {
if (element.is(":radio")) {
    error.appendTo(element.closest("[class*='col-sm-']"));
}
else if (element.parents('.selectric-wrapper').size() > 0) {
    console.log('selectric error');
    error.appendTo(element.closest('[class*="col-sm-"]'));
}
else {
    error.appendTo(element.parent());
}
}

//
// Name:  highlight
// Description:  Used by the validator to show the error messages.
//
function highlightValidator(element, errorClass, validClass, counter) {
var $parent = $(element).parent();

// remove icon and success spans if any
$parent.find("span.form-control-feedback, span.sr-only").remove();

// add ".error" class to input element
$(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);

// add Bootstrap ".has-error" class to parent div.form-group element
$(element).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-success").addClass("has-error has-feedback");

// need to have it check to see if span already added
// only add for non radio or non select input elements
if (!$(element).is(":radio, select, textarea, :checkbox, .btn") && !$(element).hasClass("datepicker")) {
    counter++;

    var $spans = $parent.find("span");

    // check to make sure error spans are not already in form-group before attempting to append after input
    if ($spans.length == 0) {
        // add span element with ".glyphicon" ".glyphicon-remove" ".form-control-feedback" classes after input
        $(element).after("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback' aria-hidden='true'></span>");
        $(element).after("<span id='inputError" + counter + "Status'" + " class='sr-only'>(error)</span>");
    }
}
}

//
// Name:  unhighlightValidator
// Description:  Used by the validator to hide the error messages.
//
function unhighlightValidator(element, errorClass, validClass, counter) {
var $parent = $(element).parent();

// remove icon and success spans if any
$parent.find("span.form-control-feedback, span.sr-only").remove();

// remove ".error" class from input element
$(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);

if (!$(element).is(":radio, select, textarea, :checkbox, .btn") && !$(element).hasClass("datepicker")) {
    // // remove Bootstrap ".has-error" class from parent div.form-group element
    $(element).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error").addClass("has-success has-feedback");

    var $spans = $parent.find("span");

    if ($spans.length == 0 && !$(element).is("select")) {
        $(element).after("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback' aria-hidden='true'></span>");
        $(element).after("<span id='inputSuccess" + counter + "Status'" + " class='sr-only'>(error)</span>");
    }
} else if ($(element).parents('.selectric-wrapper').size() > 0) {
    $(element).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error").addClass("has-success has-feedback");
}
}
```

Here is the EditInfo.cshtml file script section.

```
@section scripts {   
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/EditInfo.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/app.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

The section `scripts` is rendered in the layout file.

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Next, the EditInfo.cshtml page. Here is a sample, with the first item, in this case a text box. The form tag is closed at the end, with no inputs being left out. The javascript file does use the names and not id's for elements.

```
<div class="frontpage">
<form class="form-horizontal" id="frmEditInfo" name="frmEditInfo">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="workCell" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Work Cellphone</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="tel" name="workCell" id="workCell" class="form-control" placeholder="Work Cellphone">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Finally, here is the actual javascript file, EditInfo.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var counter = 0;

$("#frmEditInfo").validate({
    ignore: [],
    rules: {
        personalEmail:{
            email: true
            //pattern: /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,15}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/i
        },
        otherEmail: {
            email: true
            //pattern: /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,15}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/i
        },
        workCell: {
            required: true,
            phoneUS: true
            //pattern: /^\(?\d{3}\)?\s?-?\d{3}\s?-?\d{4}$/
        },
        personalCell: {
            phoneUS: true
            //pattern: /^\(?\d{3}\)?\s?-?\d{3}\s?-?\d{4}$/
        },
        otherPhone: {
            phoneUS: true
            //pattern: /^\(?\d{3}\)?\s?-?\d{3}\s?-?\d{4}$/
        }
    },
    messages: {
        personalEmail: {
            email: "Invalid Email"
        },
        otherEmail: {
            email: "Invalid Email"
        },
        workCell: {
            phoneUS: "Invalid Phone Number"
        },
        personalCell: {
            phoneUS: "Invalid Phone Number"
        },
        otherPhone: {
            phoneUS: "Invalid Phone Number"
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        errorPlacementValidator(error, element);
    },
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        counter++;
        highlightValidator(element, errorClass, validClass, counter);
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        counter++;
        unhighlightValidator(element, errorClass, validClass, counter);
    }


});

$('#workCell').inputmask("(999) 999-9999");
$('#personalCell').inputmask("(999) 999-9999");
$('#otherPhone').inputmask("(999) 999-9999");
});
```

EDIT: Removed unnecessary code regarding submit function.

Comment: You don't need the full and minified versions of everything.  Pick one or the other.  Including both versions of same script will break things.

Comment: Are you using Unobtrusive-Validation plugin?  Might be good idea to mention that either way.

Comment: @Sparky I'm not using the full regex. I just didn't want to delete and lose it. And no it doesn't. I didn't know that was a thing, my bad.

Comment: *"not using the full regex"*  ~ how does that have anything to do with either of my comments?

Comment: @Sparky, my apologies, you are correct. I had thought you were under the impression I was using both the shortcut (phoneUS) and regex that I wrote in the validation rules.


By 'full and minified', am I correct you are refering to stuff.js and stuff.min.js? Where am I using this and how would I be able to correct it?

Comment: Check your bundles... it seems like you're duplicating everything with min versions.  Looks like validate three times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. 
TL;DR The js file wasn't correctly added in `BundleConfig.cs`

After a lot of research, I put the code into jsfiddle, and it worked. So I went back and made sure I had updated JS files and such. Eventually I found the problem, which was in the BundleConfig file. The bundle that included the `jquery-validate.js` file was named incorrectly. That is not to say that it was the only issue, Sparky helped me with my rules (not writing my own regex), not using `method.min.js` file when I was also using `method.js`. I figured I should post the answer just to set the record straight.